# How to constantly update offline android database through online database?

Tags: android, database

I'm planning to create an android app for customers(shop) that have an offline database so the users can use it offline. After that I will create a Website for the owner of the shop so he/she can post new items on the website then save it to the online database. My question is how can I constantly update the offline database of the android app whenever there's is a new item on the online database? Any suggestion or theory that I can use will help me a lot. I'm new in android and web sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I personally did for one app was that I updated my device database whenever the user went online. I saved the current database version using `SharedPreferences` and then the app checks the servers' database version -- which was saved in a text file for easy reading and parsing by the Android Device. If there's a mismatch, the device downloads the database update, essentially performing a sync process. It downloads the entire database (if done properly, it shouldn't be too much) and photos if need be.

Basically what happens is that your app will check (once it goes online) if there's a database update available.

Comment: One more question sir, what database shall I use for android and for my website? MySQL? for both of them? will it connect?

Comment: Mine was rather inefficient as it was only a proof of concept. I used MySQL for the website and SQLite for my Android App.

Comment: So do you sync every time the app is open or you schedule the sync?

Answer (score 1):

this link might be helpful [sync remote mysql db to sqlite](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-remote-mysql-db-to-sqlite-on-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Just save a time stamp on the device of when was the last time the offline database was updated.

Do the same each time for the online database - each time the user adds something from the web, just save a time stamp.

So, when you launch the application, just compare the two time stamps. If the time stamp of the online database is greater than the one on the device - sync the new items.